# How to make API calls inside a for loop to wait for one to finish before making another in Angular using observables?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a for loop that makes one API call depending on the length of the array if the length of the array is 6 so there will be 6 API calls, the problem is that are asynchronous calls so some of them gave me errors, How can I do to every API call inside of the loop wait until its done so then can be another call?

I really want to do it with observables and not promises

This is my service where I do the call

```js
 respuestaEncuesta(respuesta:any,idEncuesta:number,idPregunta:number){
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL+'api/encuestas/'+idEncuesta+'/preguntas/'+idPregunta+'/respuesta',respuesta,this.httpOptions)
  }
```

Here is my for loop, the only thing I do in the function sends the array and then do the loop, this is on my ts and here I call the function that does the API call inside a service

```js
for (let j=0;j < this.obj.data.length; j++){
      this.userService.respuestaEncuesta(this.obj.data[j],this.id,this.auxPreguntas[j])
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          let auxRes:any;
          auxRes = res;
          if(auxRes.estado == 'success'){
            console.log('successful call')
          }
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err)
        }
      )
    }
```

I tried with forkjoin like this but didn't work some of the requests are not sending

```js
respuesta:any = [];
for (let j=0;j < this.obj.data.length; j++){
this.respuesta.push(this.userService.respuestaEncuesta(this.obj.data[j],this.id,this.auxPreguntas[j])) 
    }
forkJoin(this.respuesta)
    .subscribe(
      results => {
        console.log(results);
      }
    )
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593611/wait-for-observable-in-for-loop-to-finish-before-continuing-loop-in-angular-5

Comment: @Zack No, sorry I want to do it without recursivity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a sequence of http requests in Angular 6 using RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560652/how-to-make-a-sequence-of-http-requests-in-angular-6-using-rxjs)

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap)

**example**

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ms2yst?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
let data = [1, 2, 3];
of(...data)
.pipe(
  // use a concatmap
  concatMap(value => {
    return of(value).pipe(delay(2000)) 
    // this represents your request
  })
)
.subscribe(item => {
  console.log(item);
  // requests should now be made one after another, do whatever
});
```

Comment: I tried this and said this `error`  Property pipe does not exist on type Observable<ArrayBuffer>[]

Comment: Ah right. I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ms2yst?file=src/app/app.component.ts. I ll edit the post accordingly ;)

Comment: I put it and it's not working please check my updated question, if you can please give me an example with my code

Comment: You should prep the data so it is useful enough to create the arguments of your http-request. But I am sure you can do all of that yourself.